# Can JNDI DB connection be stored in Session?

Tags: java

I am connecting MS SQL Server through JNDI. My app will connect to DB once and will store the con for future use. I am able to connect and retrieve required data successfully. However, when the DB gets restarted, I lose my connection getting "Connection reset by peer: socket write error".

Hence I need to restart my app. So, I decided to create connection whenever my conn is closed through code. Is it the right way to do? Should I store the conn in session?

Answer (score 1):

Do not! Use something like [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) which creates a connection pool from where you can lookup connections. When you need a connection look it up from the pool and when you are done, release it back to the pool. The Connection object life cycle would be managed by the dbcp library.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer here: use a connection pool.

I would recommand the [Tomcat one](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2013/01/30/Using-Tomcat-JDBC-connection-pool-in-a-standalone-environment) instead of the old Apache DBCP, even for standalone/non-web applications, not running in any container

Comment: yes, I agree. If it is a web application deployed in servers like Tomcat, JBoss etc the use datasource provided by the server. If it is a stand alone Java app, Apache DBCP still holds good. :)

Comment: @Richie no I mean if this is a standalone app, like a batch, I recommand to use Tomcat connection pool which is faster

Answer (score 0):

Don't. It will be brittle.

Use a connection pool, preferably one that can probe the connection before handing out to ensure it is valid.

If your container does not provide such a pool, you can bring your own in your web application.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt keep active connection to DB when you dont need it. As soon as your task is complete and no more data need processing you should close it. When you need it again ask datasource for new one.
 So you want keep somewhere DataSource object for this DB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. So can I call dataSource.getConnection() every time when I request data? and close that conn when completed. Pls clarify...

Comment: yes, but DataSource will decide if will close connection - see NickJ answer how to use DB pooling connections

Comment: Will dataSource.getConnection() retrieve connections from the dpcp. Is that not creating new connections for every request, if called for every request?

Comment: that depends how you configure it, how fast should be connection closed after you tell it to close. Its called pooling cause it may return some older still active connection and not create one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what connection pools such as Apache DBCP are for.

Keep a reference to the pool in session and use it whenever you want a connection, like this example:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java?revision=1143885&view=markup